# UI Grid Angular, grid renders but doesn't display data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

What am I missing here? The grid renders with no errors, blank rows... I checked and JSON is coming in fine up to this point `$scope.gridOptions.data = response['data'];` It seems like its rendering the empty array and never getting to the actual data...

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.myData = [];
        $scope.loading = true;

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableSorting: true,
            columnDefs: [
              { name: 'Id', field: 'PK_Inspection' },
              { name: 'Employee Id', field: 'EmployeeId' },
              { name: 'Employee Name', field: 'EmployeeName' },
              { name: 'Equipment Id', field: 'EquipmentId' },
              { name: 'Equipment Name', field: 'EquipmentName' },
              { name: 'Sequence', field: 'SequenceName' },
              { name: 'Details', field: 'SequenceDetails' },
              { name: 'Type', field: 'SequenceTypeName' },
              { name: 'Shift', field: 'ShiftName' },
              { name: 'Status', field: 'StatusName' }
            ],
            data:[]
        };

        $http.get('/Home/GetAllData')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.gridOptions.data = response['data'];
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                console.log("Error Receiving Data.");
            })
            .finally(function () {
                $scope.loading = false;
                console.log($scope.gridOptions.data);

            });

    }]);
```

Data being passed over to `$scope.gridOptions.data`:

```
[
    {
        "PK_Inspection": 1,
        "EmployeeId": "4433112",
        "EmployeeName": "",
        "EquipmentId": "1122113",
        "EquipmentName": "",
        "SequenceName": "UNIT 1",
        "SequenceDetails": "Bent, Dented, Broken, Torn or Deformed Parts.",
        "SequenceTypeName": "Visual Inspection",
        "ShiftName": "Day",
        "StatusName": "OK"
    },
    {
        "PK_Inspection": 2,
        "EmployeeId": "4433112",
        "EmployeeName": "",
        "EquipmentId": "1122113",
        "EquipmentName": "",
        "SequenceName": "UNIT 2",
        "SequenceDetails": "Charge, Water Levels, Vent Caps in place, Power Disconnect works.",
        "SequenceTypeName": "Visual Inspection",
        "ShiftName": "Day",
        "StatusName": "OK"
    }
]
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin text-center" ng-show="loading"></i>
    <div id="mainGrid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the response data?

Comment: @Phil I updated the question with the response data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, and it appears that my problem was a mixture of two things.

1. The incoming JSON was a string, I'm not 100% sure if I needed to convert to an object by using `JSON.parse` then pass it along to the `$scope.gridOptions.data` but that could've been the issue for the code I posted in my original question above.
2. After more research I found a great in-depth example in the official Angular UI Grid docs. Following this technique i was able to get the data rendered correctly.

   ```
   var rowCount = 0;
   var i = 0;
   $scope.refreshData = function () {
       $scope.loading = true;
       $scope.myData = [];

       $http.get('/Home/GetAllData')
           .success(function (response) {
               var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
               rowCount = jsonObj.length;

               jsonObj.forEach(function (row) {
                   row.id = i; i++;
                   $scope.myData.push(row);
               });
               $scope.loading = false;

           })
           .error(function() {
               $scope.loading = false;
               console.log("Error retrieving data.");
           });
    };
   ```

In the example it makes use of a string value in gridOptions.data called `myData` which refers to an object on your scope to watch. So what I'm doing is just pushing each row once the GET request completes.

The full example is [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBVpID5iQSJl1w9xlPBF?p=preview) via Punklr.

Answer (score 0):

For me below code worked, once i change data i call below code

```
if ($scope.gridApi ) {
       $scope.$timeout(() => {
          $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();
          $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
       }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You access the wrong JSON data from response (taken from your respone sample, array is not in 'data' name). Your response has no-name array with data, in your code you do:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = response['data'];
```

It should be:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = response;
```

Comment: Actually i'm accessing the data property inside the response object. Response is an object which consists of data property and others. The JSON is in data. If i don't use `response.data` or `response['data']` then i'm simply passing the full object.

Comment: When using the `then` method of the response promise (as OP is doing), the argument to the callback function is the entire response object. See the *"Returns"* section here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `fieldId` like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = 
{
     enableSorting: true,
     columnDefs: [
          { name: 'Id', field: 'PK_Inspection' },
          { name: 'Employee Id', field: 'employeeId' },
          { name: 'Employee Name', field: 'employeeName' },
          { name: 'Equipment Id', field: 'equipmentId' },
          { name: 'Equipment Name', field: 'equipmentName' },
          { name: 'Sequence', field: 'sequenceName' },
          { name: 'Details', field: 'sequenceDetails' },
          { name: 'Type', field: 'sequenceTypeName' },
          { name: 'Shift', field: 'shiftName' },
          { name: 'Status', field: 'statusName' }
        ],
     data:[]
};
```